# Proof that Verlet integration conserves energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, computational-physics

I was reading about different integrators that one might use to solve the system of differential equations which governs the $n$-body problem. I read that the Verlet integrator is time-reversible, and thus conserves energy.

I don't understand why time-reversibility implies energy conservation.

Suppose I know the position and velocity of each of $n$ particles in the system at some time $t_0$. I calculate the energy $E_0$ of the system at time $t_0$. I use the Verlet integrator to calculate the approximate positions and velocity of the particles at time $t_0+dt$ (one time step) and I recalculate the energy of the system and find it to be $E_1$. Is it true that $E_0=E_1$? And is there an easy way to prove this?

Comment: Seems related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76323/ (doesn't ask for proof, just what energy conservation means in this context)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the Verlet integrator only conserves energy in the limit $\Delta t\to 0$. In practice it produces energy drift, although the long-term energy drift is smaller than for most integrators.

Regarding your question, the gist of the argument is that integrators that are *not* time-reversible do *not* exhibit so-called area-preservation. This basically means that the volume of phase space of constant energy $E$ will evolve to a *larger* volume of the phase space over time, and hence it will necessarily span a region of phase space with different energies.

The rigorous proof of this property is complicated which is why most sources (including this answer of mine) omit the details and provide a handwavy justification. Frenkel and Smit's book Understanding Molecular Simulation provides a review of this subject with plenty of citations, if you're interested.

Comment: I still don't understand why time reversibility implies smaller energy drift. I ran an n-body simulation,using Euler and  Verlet, and the Verlet was orders of magnitude better at conserving energy. Is there at least an iintuitive explanation why?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou Imagine the volume of phase space that contains every configuration with a fixed energy $E$. Now evolve each point forward through time. This volume *should* remain unchanged ([Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian))) but if time reversibility does not hold then this volume will change (and increase, typically). The larger this volume is, the more non-$E$ energy states become accessible.